# Add count classes for nested list elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
  <ul class="parent">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul></ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <ul></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

I need to add count classes for all nested lists in this markup, to reach this:

```
  <ul class="parent">
    <ul class="level-1">
      <li>
        <ul class="level-2"></ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="level-2">
          <li>
            <ul class="level-3"></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="level-1">
      <li>
        <ul class="level-2"></ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul class="level-2">
          <li>
            <ul class="level-3"></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

So i do this:

```
var parent_ul = $('.parent');

if (parent_ul.doesExist()){
    var parent_ul_lists = parent_ul.find('ul');

    parent_ul_lists.each(function(){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < parent_ul_lists.length; i++) {
            $(this).eq(i).addClass('level-' + i);
        }
    })
}
```

But in output i have class test `level-1` for all of parent list childrens. Can anybody help?

Comment: What is `doesExist()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.parent ul').addClass(function(){
   return "level-"+$(this).parents('ul').length;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/bwym4/1/)

Comment: This does work, but is inefficient because the parents call on every child element checks every parent node in the whole DOM structure.  It also only works if the parent `ul` does not exist in some other `ul` up the chain.

Comment: Downvote because of (1) inefficiency and (2) the parent inside ul problem. Explanations:
 1) Inefficiency: `$(this).parents('ul')` checks the parent, and every parent's parent of every matched element.  This causes a gigantic Big(O) problem.  Using `parents()` jQuery has to check every parent up the chain to see if it matches the `ul` selector.
 2) Parent inside ul: Consider `<ul id='predecessor'><ul class='parent'>...</ul></ul>` . If this were the case, then `$(this).parents('ul').length` would return `level + 1` instead of `level`.

Comment: Overexagerated perhaps, I apologize if I offended.  I'm only trying to supply the best advice that I know how.  With the simple `ul` structure provided in the question, `parents()` performs a total of 20 comparisons.  If you include standard html tags (`<html><body>`) the count shoots up to 34, and thats only adding 2 standard parents!  If the question used standard html (missing li tags) the number just keeps growing.  As for the comment on my provided code, you can notice I used `#parent` instead of `.parent`, which would not have the mentioned effect.

Comment: @chadiusvt I did not get offended, i was just confused :) i guess you are partially correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var parent = $('.parent').children();
    next = parent;
    var i = 0;
    while (next.length) {
        parent = next;

        parent.addClass("Level_" + i);
        i++;
        next = next.children();
    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SPj3/6/)

Comment: Interesting take, but incorrect.  You are assigning a `level-#` class to li elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

```
var parent_ul = $('.parent');


var parent_ul_lists = parent_ul.find('ul');

parent_ul_lists.each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('level-'+ ($(this).parents().length -1)/2);

});
```

See working demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/qmGcC/**

**Note:** Inspect element in output to see class assigned

Comment: This gives an incorrect count if your `ul` has any other DOM element parents.  For instance, an `li` has a `div` which has the next child `ul`.

Comment: However, in your question, you have never mention about element existance different than ul li.

Answer (score 0):

You need some good 'ole recursion!

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pTLs/4/)  **UPDATE: corrected jsFiddle link**

Here is the code:

```
function labelChildUL(element, count) {
    element.children().each(function (index, value) {
        var $me = $(value);
        if ($me.is("ul")) {
            $me.addClass("level-" + (count + 1));
            labelChildUL($me, count + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            labelChildUL($me, count);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $parent = $('#parent');
    labelChildUL($parent, 0);
});
```

I also updated your html to use `id` instead of `class` for "parent":

```
<ul id='parent'>
...
```

Comment: You need to do some fixes to your fiddle, it doesn't work here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3pTLs/2/

Comment: Ah thank you, it didn't save my most recent work.  I updated it to have text in the `li` to show levels visually.